# How to downgrade from automake1.14 to 1.12 version?

Tags: 14.04

Rightnow I'm using Ubuntu14.04 and a newbie to linux. I have problem that my DroneSDK3 can only bult with automake1.12 and I want to downgrade my automake 1.14 to proper version! Is there any way to do it?
 Best regards!

Answer (score 4):

Compile yourself an old version:

```
cd
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/automake-1.12.5.tar.gz
tar xf automake-1.12.5.tar.gz
cd automake-1.12.5
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
```

- Install with `checkinstall` for a deb package and change the package name for a parallel install with the latest `automake` version:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install checkinstall
  sudo checkinstall
  ```

  Press <kbd>2</kbd>
  and change the title to: `automake1.12`
- Or the classic way

  ```
  sudo make install
  ```

`automake1.12` is installed in `/usr/local/bin` and the latest version from the repositories in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: This is useful.  I am trying to build something that requires two versions of automake  (1.14 and 1.16) so it would be nice to do more of a side by side install.  Not sure if that is possible with checkinstall.